# Error while downloading and unziping a file in Python: BadZipeFile error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, zip

I'm trying to download and unzip a file from github, but I am totally stuck in the first lines and I have no clue of why the BadZipFile errors is being raised - actually, I do not know what it is and I could not find anything that could help me. I mean, the error "File is not a zip file" means nothing to me since the file I am trying to download and extract IS a zip file.

The code is:

```
import os
import urllib
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = 'https://github.com/alura-cursos/imersaodados3/tree/main/dados/'
FARMACOS_PATH = os.path.join('datasets' , 'fármacos')
FARMACOS_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + 'dados_experimentos.zip'  

def fetch_data(farmacos_url=FARMACOS_URL, farmacos_path=FARMACOS_PATH):
if not os.path.isdir(farmacos_path):
    os.makedirs(farmacos_path)
zip_path = os.path.join(farmacos_path, "dados_experimentos.zip")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(farmacos_url, zip_path)
http_response = urlopen(farmacos_url)
dados_experimentos = ZipFile(BytesIO(http_response.read()))
dados_experimentos.extractall(path=farmacos_path)

fetch_data()
```

But when I run it raises the following error:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-26-3197a88ee54e> in <module>
----> 1 fetch_data()

<ipython-input-25-f8e2f09d9e87> in fetch_data(farmacos_url, farmacos_path)
  5     urllib.request.urlretrieve(farmacos_url, zip_path)
  6     http_response = urlopen(farmacos_url)
----> 7     dados_experimentos = ZipFile(BytesIO(http_response.read()))
  8     dados_experimentos.extractall(path=farmacos_path)

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1256         try:
   1257             if mode == 'r':
-> 1258                 self._RealGetContents()
   1259             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1260                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1323             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1324         if not endrec:
-> 1325             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1326         if self.debug > 1:
   1327             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I don't know what it means. The folder is being created correctly and the zip file is being downloaded correctly, but it simply does not unzip since it is ~~not a zip file.

Any help?

Comment: What you can try is do a ```print(http_response.read())```  to see whether or not that is exactly the right response you're expecting BytesIO() to receive.

Comment: Write whatever you read to a zip file and try unzipping manually.

Comment: I tried to unzip it manually and I got an error saying that there was no file found in there. That makes me even more confused